# Crash when initializing CoreML model: Error Domain=com.apple.CoreML Code=0 "Error in declaring network."

Tags: ios, swift, coreml

I have an app on the App Store and I'm getting its error logs from Crashlytics. One of the most frequent errors the users get (and the one I failed miserably to reproduce) occurs when initializing a CoreML model in my project. Here is how I initialize the model:

```
class VisionManager: NSObject {
  /// Prediction model
  private static let model = MobileNet()

  ...

  override init() {
    super.init()

    guard let visionModel = try? VNCoreMLModel(for: VisionManager.model.model) else {
      // this case should never happen as we know for sure that the model we are using is an image classification model
      fatalError("The CoreML model being used is not compatible with the Vision framework.")
    }

    ...
  }

...
}
```

The error, as seen on Crashlytics, reads as follows:

> fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=com.apple.CoreML Code=0 "Error in declaring network." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Error in declaring network.}: file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-900.0.65.2/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift, line 181

And the stack trace shows that the error is thrown when executing the `guard` block. Actually, it goes deeper and shows that the error was thrown inside the static initialization at the top, when calling the initializer. The initializer, together with the whole MobileNet.swift class is automatically generated and looks like this:

```
init(contentsOf url: URL) throws {
  self.model = try MLModel(contentsOf: url)
}

/// Construct a model that automatically loads the model from the app's bundle
convenience init() {
  let bundle = Bundle(for: MobileNet.self)
  let assetPath = bundle.url(forResource: "MobileNet", withExtension:"mlmodelc")
  try! self.init(contentsOf: assetPath!)
}
```

It seems obvious that the error is thrown calling the `init(contentsOf url: URL)` method. However, since this is a generated file, I believe there isn't much I can do to tackle this error.

One possibility is that the compiled `.mlmodelc` file is not copied to the bundle somehow, and when trying to initialize the `MobileNet` object with that `URL`, we get an uncaught error. Is that even possible?

Any ideas or pointers on this issue is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do all users get this error? Or do some users get this error all the time? Or do some users get this error some of the times? If it's "some users but all of the time" then perhaps they are using a different iOS 11 version than the users for whom the app does not crash. In other words, it's possible that something changed in Core ML in iOS 11.x and people who have not updated to this version get the crash.

Comment: Not all users get this error. I and the other developers in the team never got it. There also doesn't seem to be a pattern on which devices and OS versions get it either. I can see all sorts of OS versions such as 11.0.0, 11.0.3, 11.1.0, 11.1.1, 11.2.0 that got this error and devices such as iPhone 6, 6 Plus, SE, 7, 7 Plus and X.

Comment: How many MB is the model? Maybe the devices are just running out of free memory at that point.

Comment: I was also suspicious of that since most of the devices have less than 10% memory left when they crash. However, there are also devices with more than 40% memory available at the time of the crash. The app as a whole takes no more than 100 MB's on startup, so I don't think it's because of the memory.

Answer (score 2):

> It seems obvious that the error is thrown calling the init(contentsOf url: URL) method. However, since this is a generated file, I believe there isn't much I can do to tackle this error.

FYI, you can copy this generated file into a new file and use it instead to initialize the model (just rename the classes inside the new file).  Then, try changing this line in your new file:

```
let bundle = Bundle(for: MobileNet.self)
```

to:

```
let bundle = Bundle.main
```

I'm not sure if this will fix your particular problem, but it did for me when I moved the generated file into a Cocoapod

Answer (score 0):

Better to read the errors at the top of the output panel in Xcode. There should be an error something like this which shows the actual error: "A Core ML custom neural network layer requires an implementation named 'scaling' which was not found in the global namespace.

In my case, I had an unsupported layer in the model I used so I need to write MLCustomLayer.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/core_ml_api/creating_a_custom_layer